# django file upload doesn't work

Tags: django, templates, file-upload, view, image-uploading

Im working on web app project for study. I have a problem with file upload.
It works for an admin, but for regular user files don't save. It must be a problem with mu **views.py** or **template html**

1. **forms.py**

   ```
   class DocumentUpload(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Form
           fields = ('file',)
   ```
2. **models.py**

   ```
   class Form(TimeStampedModel, TitleSlugDescriptionModel):
       author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
       is_final = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       is_result_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.title

       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('form-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
   ```
3. **views.py**

   ```
   def create_form(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           user = request.user
           data = ParseRequest(request.POST)
           print(data.questions())
           print(data.form())
           parsed_form = data.form()
           parsed_questions = data.questions()

           # tworzy formularz o podanych parametrach
           formfile = DocumentUpload(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
           if formfile.is_valid():
               form = formfile.save(commit=False)
               print(form)
               form.author = user
               form.title = parsed_form['title']
               form.is_final = parsed_form['is_final']
               form.is_result_public = parsed_form['is_result_public']
               form.description = parsed_form['description']
               form.save()
               # zapisuje pytania z ankiety wraz z odpowienimi pytaniami
               for d in parsed_questions:
                   question = Question(form=form, question=d['question'])
                   question.save()
                   # dla kazdego pytania zapisz wszystkie opcje odpowiadania
                   for opt in d['options']:
                       option = Option(question=question, option=opt)
                       option.save()
               return render(request, 'forms/form_form.html', {})
       else:
           form = DocumentUpload()
           return render(request, 'forms/form_form.html', {'form': form})
   ```
4. **create_form.html**

   ```
       {% block content %}
       <form method="post" id="form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
       {%csrf_token %}
       <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="form-title">Tytuł formularza</label>
            <input id="form-title" class="form-control" type="text" 
                                     placeholder="Tytuł" required/>
        </div>
           {{ form.as_p }}
       <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="zapisz"/>
       </form>
       {% endblock %}
   ```

   5.**settings.py**

   ```
   ....
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
      'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
       }
   }
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   ]
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
   ...
   ```

   5.**urls.py**

   ```
   if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += 
        static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
            document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Comment: Can you please share the solution how you got it worked? I'm still facing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `action` on your `form` just like so :

```
<form action="{% url 'name_of_your_function' %}" method="post" id="form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
...
</form>
```

action must contain your url name, example :

```
url(url_regex, views.function, name="name_of_your_function"),
```

Comment: i did, but still doesnt work. I have no error, form just save without file.

Comment: use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` under `form.is_valid()` to check if the form goes through, it'll show on your console as `(pdb) ...`, if it works then try to look inside the console what's not working by typing the code below step by step.

Comment: i tried to use this debbuger, but i dont see any mistake

Comment: @JanekWojciechowski If I understand well, now the form saves all the informations for the user, except files then this should be a problem with your media configuration, could you show me your urls.py and settings.py ? Are you on localhost ?

Comment: yes it is true, all informations saves correctly except file. It works like there is no file (it does not exist). I edit and add some part of urls and settings. If it is not enough let me know.

Comment: @JanekWojciechowski Is there any file that is uploaded not in your django/admin but on your folder ?

Comment: Im not sure if i understand you correctly. In my '/media/' folder i have only  2 files uploaded as an admin and there is nothing else. There is no mark of files that i try to upload as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified an `upload_to` attribute for your `FileField` in `models.py`.

Add a directory for your field, like,

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Your form is all fine and the file has been sent through request, but Django does not know where to save the file, until you define it in your models.

Read more about it in the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)

Comment: I add, so now in my model: **file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)**, i made migrations, but still dont work. Everything works for admin, so i think that it knows where to save it.

Comment: any other ideas?